# Backup site and restore to exact identical

Tags: 2013, backup

We are using SharePoint 2013, and the VM is a bit sick. I would like to do a full back up of a site (1 app web -> 1 site collection), so I will be able to import it in a new SharePoint farm.

Is there a way to know the size of the back up ?

What should I use if I want to perform a full (really full) backup : I want to keep permissions, logo, parameters, etc.

May I use : `Export-SPWeb` ? `Backup-SPFarm` ? `Backup-SPSite` ?

Is there any considerations ?

TIA

EDIT: 
On the source SharePoint farm (only 1 server with SQL installed on it):

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
15     0      4420   1017
```

On the destination SharePoint farm (2 SP Servers and 1 SQL):

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
15     0      4569   1000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using Backup-SPSite, it keeps the permissions, lists, items, etc ... But it will not save the logo if it's a custom one because "Backup-SPSite" saves the Content Database and the logo has 99% chance to be in the file system, under the SharePoint hive (15 Folder). Another recommandation, use the "UseSqlSnapshot" parameter as it keeps user reading and writing in your site collection while you're doing the backup

You can refer to this link : https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607901.aspx

You can simply restore your site collection in your new environment by running the inverse operation which is "Restore-SPSite". (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607788.aspx).

- To get the site collection size, use this powershell script :

  $sc = get-spsite http://sharepoint
  $sc.Usage

this should prompt you something like that:

```
Storage           : 9621220
Bandwidth         : 0
Visits            : 0
Hits              : 0
DiscussionStorage : 0
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I checked my db is 20Go. Does the backup weight the same ? I mention the logo, but in fact, I don't care about the logo, I just want a real copy of my site collection. During the backup (how much time it takes to complete?) users won't be able to use the site, right ? or data corruption may appear (as I read on microsoft) ?

Comment: The backup operation may take some time to complete, and yes, the size of your site collection is the same as your content db size. IMO, I would suggest doing this during off-hours, the night, with a scheduled task. You could use the "UseSqlSnapshot" but the result will not take in consideration the last users updates.

Comment: Ok, so the best practice would be to do this off-hours without `UseSqlSnapshot` (because not needed) right ? Another question, do you have any ideas about the time it will take ? 1hour or 7hours for example ? can you confirm that `Backup-SPSite` have no impact on the site itself ? (except performances). Last question, no problem importing the backup while Farm are in different versions ? (Dest > source is enough no ?)

Comment: If you'll be doing that in off-hours, there's no need to user 'UseSqlSnapshot' parameter. For the time that it will take, I can't tell you exactly how much it will take, but I think it will not exceed 2 hours, but I can be wrong. Finally, I can confirm that 'Backup-SPSite' has no impact on the site itself. The risk is that your site goes in a read only mode. If that happened, don't panic, just run this script :

    Set-SPSite -Identity "<SiteCollection>" -LockState "Unlock"

(https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263238.aspx)

Comment: Hope it helps. You can email me if needed at gahbiche.khalil@gmail.com

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21775/discussion-between-nico-and-kgahbiche).